# writing C function using only recursion

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

I want to find out if the sum of even numbers in the array is equal to the sum of odd numbers, using only recursion and without any additional functions, except recursion and without any static variables.

If the sum of odd numbers is equal to the sum of even numbers, the function returns 1, else it returns 0. All the numbers in the array are non negative.

The function signature should look like this:

```
function(unsigned int a[], int n)
```

Until now I have written the following:

```
function(unsigned int a[], int n)
{ 
    if(n==0) return 0;
    return (a[0]%2)?((a[0]+function(a+1,n-1)):(-a[0]+function(a+1,n-1));
}
```

This function returns the total sum required but not the answer to the question (which is 1 if yes and 0 if no).

Yes this is a part of an assignment but I cannot solve it without additional functions that are not allowed.

Comment: Seems impossible  given the signature. Might be possible with a different signature.

Comment: I suppose, you are trying to implement wrong alorithm.... consider using static (or global) variables for storing sum(s)

Comment: Are you allowed to modify the array as you go along?

Comment: Darn.. Just written a nice answer assuming we are talking about odd and even indices..

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Even for even/odd indices, it is possible.

Comment: @jxh Without extra parameters and without modifying the input data? Would be grateful to see the implementation.

Comment: @jxh Oh well, based on your answer I think I see the possible modification.. will examine it closer.

Comment: Pathological case of `n==0`.  Your code returns 0.  Yet the sum of odd values, of which there are none, is the same as the sum of odd values.  So I would expected a return of 1.  Suspect it is not highly important even if it does not meet the stated goals.

Answer (score 9):

If we assume no overflow in the calculations:

```
int function (unsigned int a[], int n) {
    if (n >= 0) return !function(a, -n-1);
    if (++n == 0) return 0;
    return function(a+1, n) + ((a[0] % 2) ? -a[0] : a[0]);
}
```

> On first call into the function, the `n` is nonnegative, and reflects the size of the array. We recursively call the function and logically negate the result, and arithmetically negate `n+1`. The off by one negation allows `-1` to represent `0`
>
> On subsequent calls, the sum of evens are positively accumulated, and odds are negatively accumulated. The negative `n` is incremented until it reaches `0`. The result of the recursive calls on the negative `n` is `0` if the sums are equal, and non-zero otherwise.
>
> On return to the outermost call, the logical negation flips it so that `1` is returned if the sums are equal and `0` otherwise.

I'll leave it as an exercise to appropriately deal with overflow.

Comment: nice, short and elegant !

Comment: i just forgot to mention one thing which is: if n==0 return 1; because an empty array is considered as correct because the sum of evens equals to the odds, and both are 0 on this case.

Comment: @evgniytayarov Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

A mod to [@jxh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37799599/2410359) nifty answer.

A typical complaint against recursion function is in using up the stack.  With `N` elements, having `N` levels of recursion may exhaust the recursion limit.

The following instead uses `log2(N)` levels of recursion by dividing the array in half per each call.

```
int function(const int a[], int n) {
  if (n > 0) return !function(a, -n);
  if (n == 0) return 0;
  if (n == -1) return (a[0] % 2) ? -a[0] : a[0];
  int half = n/2;
  int left = function(a, half);
  int right = function(&a[-half], -(-n - -half));
  return left + right;
}
```

Comment: Nice (upvoted). I would probably change the last 4 lines to `return function(a, n/2) + function(a-n/2, n-n/2);`

Comment: @jxh True, your simplification is correct.  This answer posted in steps as it was easy to mess up the math considering that sneaky `-` sign your nifty trick employs.

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution which is much more complex than yours and in a bad and unneeded way.

```
int balanced(unsigned int a[], int n)
{
    if (n <= 2)
    {
        int odd = 0, even = 0;
        if (a[0]%2 == 0) even += a[0];
        else odd += a[0];
        if (a[1]%2 == 0 && n == 2) even += a[1];
        else if (n == 2) odd += a[1];
        return (odd == even);
    }

    if (a[0]%2 == 0 && a[1]%2 == 0)
    {
        a[1] += a[0];
        return balanced(a+1, n-1);
    }
    if (a[0]%2 == 0 && a[2]%2 == 0)
    {
        a[2] += a[0];
        return balanced(a+1, n-1);
    }
    if (a[1]%2 == 0 && a[2]%2 == 0)
    {
        a[2] += a[1];
        a[1] = a[0];
        return balanced(a+1, n-1);
    }
    if (a[0]%2 == 0)
    {
        if (a[0] >= a[1]+a[2])
        {
            a[0] -= (a[1]+a[2]);
            a[2] = a[0];
            return balanced(a+2,n-2);
        }
        else
        {
            a[1] = a[1]+a[2]-a[0]-1;
            a[2] = 1;
            return balanced(a+1,n-1);
        }
    }
    if (a[1]%2 == 0)
    {
        if (a[1] >= a[0]+a[2])
        {
            a[1] -= (a[0]+a[2]);
            a[2] = a[1];
            return balanced(a+2,n-2);
        }
        else
        {
            a[0] = a[0]+a[2]-a[1]-1;
            a[2] = 1;
            a[1] = a[0];
            return balanced(a+1,n-1);
        }
    }
    if (a[2]%2 == 0)
    {
        if (a[2] >= a[1]+a[0])
        {
            a[2] -= (a[1]+a[0]);
            return balanced(a+2,n-2);
        }
        else
        {
            a[1] = a[1]+a[0]-a[2]-1;
            a[0] = 1;
            a[2] = a[0];
            return balanced(a+1,n-1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        a[2] = a[0]+a[1]+a[2];
        return balanced(a+2,n-2);
    }
}
```